# What can be used instead of cheesecloth?

Tags: substitutions, equipment, soup

My father is cooking a soup, we don't have a cheesecloth and he wants to clear the soup.

Comment: This question could also maybe help. http://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/50314/fabric-to-be-used-for-cheesecloth

Comment: @Optionparty I forgot to say that we want something better than the strainer.

Comment: A cloth held in a strainer removes many solids. A coffee filter even more.

Comment: Paper towels have worked for me when I've strained cooking oil.

Comment: @Optionparty doesn't piece of papers fall?